# FirebaseMessagingService not work if we opened the app and closed it directly before receiving any notification when the is opened

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase messaging service not being called or started in android if we opened the app and closed it directly without receiving any notification. It's not related to data payload or notification payload issues because I'm sure that the FCM setup is correct. And the most important part is the notifications work fine when the app is closed or opened if we received the first notification before killing the app.

And by tracking the device logs I'm seeing this message in event logs --> "Failed to broadcast to stopped app ": Ensure that the app has not been force stopped.

Any help to solve this issue, please ?!